# Can I assign scripts to inserted images within cells or hyperlinks in Google Sheets?

Tags: hyperlink, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm curious if there's a way to “assign script” to an image inserted into a cell using the =IMAGE(“URL”) method for Google Sheets? If not, is there a way to “assign script” to a hyperlink?

What I’d like to do is create a table of contents tab inside a Google Sheet that has many other tabs. On the table of contents, I’d love to have inserted images that act as buttons to navigate to these different tabs. I can “assign script” to images that have been inserted through the menu toolbar (e.g., Insert > Image or Insert > Drawing). However, it’s extremely clunky to have to realign my images if a new row is inserted into the table of contents.

I could always just use hyperlinks to navigate to each tab, but I don’t like how it opens a new window every time you click on the hyperlink. And I don’t like how it requires two clicks of a hyperlink (one click for the hyperlink, and then another click for the web address that pops up) to arrive at the desired tab.

So I guess, is there any option that exists to insert an image inside a cell, which can then be assigned a script?

This functionality would be so helpful.

Thanks for you time!

Comment: A sidebar might be better.  You could put a table of contents into the sidebar.  The sidebar uses HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: According to [Google Apps Script Support](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support), feature request should be posted to [Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list).

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching and haven't found a way to insert a link to anything with an Image placed with the =IMAGE () option. I've resorted to text and formatting .

You can assign a script to change tabs via "floating" Images that are Inserted via insert menu. then on the picture on the top right corner click the arrow and assign the script " goToPage1 " or whatever you decide to call your function and page. it's not as fast as Excel but it works

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    function goToPage1(){
      ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Page1"));
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I already know how to assign scripts to floating images. As I mentioned previously, I can “assign script” to images that have been inserted through the menu toolbar (e.g., Insert > Image or Insert > Drawing). However, it’s extremely clunky to have to realign my images if a new row is inserted into the table of contents. I'm looking to find an alternative to "floating" images, since they aren't tied down to the cell that I'd like them to stay in. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My only solution to this problem is to insert image within cell, then insert a transparent drawing and assign the script to that. It's not ideal, but at least it means the images are aligned perfectly, the transparent floating image just needs to be in the general area

Comment: You can also assign scripts to floating image (Image over cell)

Answer (score 0):

At this time, only to OverGrid images.

Comment: And still in 2023